# iOS opencv file not found

Tags: ios, opencv3.0

I have installed Xcode7 successfully, Now I want to use OpenCV in iOS.

I do following thing

> 1.drag opencv
>   2.framework to my project 2.c++ libary：libstd++ 
>   3.modify code in  viewcontrol to test and modify name of it to viewcontrol.mm 4precompile lanuage :objective-c++

But when run it `error:opencv2/opencv.hpp file not found`

Any help could be great!

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with the step 1 you mentioned!

You should move the unzipped version of opencv2.framework to the location of your project (project_folder). Now go to settings of your Xcode project and select General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries -> click on ‘+’ sign (to add a new framework to the project) -> Click on ‘Add Other…’ -> browse to “project_folder/opencv2.framework” -> Select it and click ‘Open’.

Now it will work fine without the error. :)

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.

Answer (score -2):

Hi i've put together a guide to getting opencv3 working with iOS.

http://kurtjacobs.weebly.com/computer-vision/up-and-running-with-opencv-30-for-ios

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.